# How to calculate the route between city X and city Y? #maps

Tags: google-maps, routes, maps, bing-maps, openstreetmap

How would you calculate the route between two cities (for cars)? I only need the major cities in Germany.

**Input**: Start-city and end-city

**Output**: Start-city, city1, city2, ..., End-city

When I'm looking into Google Maps I found the infos [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests). So it's well documented.
I see some limitation: 2500 calls per day. You need to display the graphics. That's bad.

But when I'm looking at openstreetmap or bing maps I cannot find the relevant information. Could you help me here? And are there similar services?

**Update**: I've create my own custom [routing engine](http://graphhopper.com/) in Java. Although this single requirement here wasn't the main reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used both the Google and Bing Maps APIs. Without more details or requirements, I can only provide general information.

[Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/directions/)

[Bing Route Calculation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx)

Just from some quick research, I do not believe Open Street Map has a native directions API. For other Open Street Map solutions, look [on their wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Category%3aRouting) ("YOURS" specifically may be of interest).

**Google Directions API**

For the Google Directions API, a sample request for directions between two German cities would look like : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?region=de&language=de&origin=Berlin&destination=Hamburg&sensor=false

Breaking down the [parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters) required:

- *origin* The starting location.
- *destination* The destination.
- *sensor* Is the request for a device that can sense location?

And the parameters for a German search (optional):

- *region=de* Give Google Maps an idea of where in the world to search by passing in the German top level domain code.
- *language=de* Tell Google Maps to return directions in German ([See available languages](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1))

Modify this template request as required.

---

*edit*

**Bing Routing Example**

Bing requires you to get an API key to work with any data.

A sample request for Bing for the routes between two german cities: http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes?wayPoint.1=Berlin&waypoint.2=Hamburg&culture=de-DE&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE

Required Params:

- *wayPoint.1* The starting location.
- *wayPoint.2* The destination (Note how you can easily add more waypoints).
- *key* Insert your Bing Map API key here.

Optional Params:

- *culture=de-DE* The [culture parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701709.aspx) gives Bing an idea of where to search and what to return.

**Terms of Use**

Per the [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) and [Bing](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html) Maps API terms of use, you must display an image that lets users know you are using the mapping service.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind to add an example for Bing? Has Bing the same strange limitation that one can use routing only with the images?

Comment: Both have limitations for free use. The constraints are much more flexible for commercial use, and Bing tend to be more open about the commercial options.